# Tomcat Sharing cookie between two application on same server with different host name

Tags: apache, tomcat, cookies, host

I have two applications running on a single tomcat instance.

Both applications use some apache trickery to mask their IP to a host name

rather that

```
http://123.123.123.123/appOne 
http://123.123.123.123/appTwo
```

It is

```
http://appone.com/appOne
http://apptwo.com/appTwo
```

I want to share common information between the two applications but the browser is assuming they are different.

I have set the

```
cookie.setDomain("123.123.123.123")
cookie.setPath("/")
```

both

```
request.getLocalName()
request.getLocalAddr()
```

return appone.com

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can not share information between two applications via cookie in your deployment.
A browser sees that you have two applications in different domains: `appone.com` and `apptwo.com`.
By design it will never send a cookie from one domain to another.

You can share a data between applications via a database.

Comment: I thought that was the case. Thanks for confirming

Comment: Thanks, you can promote the answer :)